# Evaluating the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}}{b+x}J_0(ax) dx$

Tags: exponential-function, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, bessel-functions, rational-functions

I've recently been trying to analytically solve an improper integral $I$ which contains a Bessel function of the first kind $J_0$, an exponential function, and the reciprocal of a linear polynomial. It looks like this:

$I(a,b,k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(ax)}{b+x}e^{-kx} dx,\quad a,b,k>0.$

I've tried two approaches, both with somewhat disappointing conclusions.

**Approach 1**

The Bessel function can be expanded in a series as

$J_0(ax)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^nn!^2}\left(ax\right)^{2n},$

such that the integral becomes

$I(a,b,k)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^na^{2n}}{4^nn!^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{b+x}e^{-kx} dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^na^{2n}}{4^nn!^2}I_n(b,k).$

This integral in the sum can be solved by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LT%5Bx%5E%282n%29%2F%28b%2Bx%29%2Cx%2Ck%5D)
by framing it as a Laplace Transform, so

$I_n(b,k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{b+x}e^{-kx} dx=(2n)!e^{bk}b^{2n}\Gamma\left(-2n,bk\right)=\frac{(2n)!e^{bk}}{k^{2n}}E_{2n+1}(bk),$

where $E_{2n+1}(bk)=(bk)^{2n}\Gamma(-2n,bk)$ is a generalized exponential integral.

Inserting the expression for $I_n$ in $I$ and rearranging then yields

$I(a,b,k)=e^{bk}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)^{2n}\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!^2}E_{2n+1}(bk)=\underline{\underline{\frac{e^{bk}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)^{2n}(n+1)_{-1/2}E_{2n+1}(bk)}},$

where the Pochhammer symbol $(n+1)_{-1/2}$ arises from

$\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}(n+1)_{-1/2}.$

I now have a way to evaluate the integral, however if $a>k$ the $\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)^{2n}$ coefficients will grow very fast to the point where I get overflow errors on my computer. I'm not sure if the sum will theoretically end up converging in such cases, but as it stands, evaluating $I$ like this is not practical.

**Approach 2**

I've read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) that an integral over the positive real axis can be rewritten using the Laplace transform as

$\int_0^{\infty}f(x)g(x) dx=\int_0^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_x(f(x))(s)\mathcal{L}_x^{-1}(g(x))(s) ds,$

so we can rewrite $I$ as

$I(a,b,k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(ax)}{b+x}e^{-kx} dx=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}_x\left(J_0(ax)e^{-kx}\right)(s)\mathcal{L}_x^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{b+x}\right)(s)ds.$

We then have

$\mathcal{L}_x\left(J_0(ax)e^{-kx}\right)(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+(s+k)^2}},\quad\mathrm{and}\quad\mathcal{L}_x^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{b+x}\right)(s)=e^{-bs},$

which can be inserted into the expression for $I$, so

$I(a,b,k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+2ks+k^2+a^2}}e^{-bs} ds $

I haven't been able to make any meaningful progress from this point. Essentially, what's inside the square root is a second degree polynomial on the form $x^2+c_1x+c_0$. Looking through Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's Table of Integrals, I've found an identity of the form

$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+c_1x)}}e^{-kx}=e^{c_1k/2}K_0\left(c_1k/2\right),$

which is *very* close to what I need except that it is missing the constant term $c_0$ in the polynomial.

If anyone has any advice or tricks on how to proceed and evaluate $I$, I'd appreciate the help. Either way, thank you for your time.

Comment: I also found the series
$$
I(a,b,k) = e^{b k}\sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+q}{2}\right)\Gamma(-q,bk)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-q}{2}\right)}(2 a b)^q
$$
which seems to converge to the result.

Comment: I got this by trying alternating integral transforms in the variables $a$ and $b$ and solving the nested transforms in Mathematica
$$
\mathcal{M}_{a \to q}[I(a,b,k)] =  \mathcal{L}_{s \to b}\left[\int_0^\infty\mathcal{M}_{a \to q}\left[\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{b \to s}\left[\frac{e^{-k x}}{(b+x)}J_0(ax)\right]\right] \; dx \right] = \frac{b^{-q} e^{b k}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{q}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)\Gamma(q,b k)
$$
with $\mathcal{M}$ the Mellin transform and $\mathcal{L}$ the Laplace transform (and their inverses with $^{-1}$).

Comment: Then performing the final inverse Mellin transform using the Ramanujan Master Theorem posing it as a sum such that if 
$$
\mathcal{M}[f] = \Gamma(s)\phi(-s)
$$
Then
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \phi(k) x^k
$$
I feel this is very similar to your sum? But I got a few to converge. 
This represents the form of a hypergeometric function but with an added incomplete gamma function, so it's not likely that a nice closed form or representation exists.

Comment: I can follow most of these steps, however I am having trouble with getting the same result when I try to use the Ramanujan Master Theorem. I assume that we introduce the variable $s=\frac{q}{2}$. If so, wouldn't the final result include the incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(-2q,bk)$?

Comment: We have to use $s=q$ to undo the original transform $\mathcal{M}_{a \to q}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-kx}}{b+x}J_0(ax)~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^{2n}x^{2n}e^{-kx}}{4^n(n!)^2(b+x)}~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^{2n}(bx)^{2n}e^{-kbx}}{4^n(n!)^2(b+bx)}~d(bx)$

$=\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^{2n}b^{2n}x^{2n}e^{-bkx}}{4^n(n!)^2(1+x)}~dx$

$=\int_1^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^{2n}b^{2n}e^{bk}(x-1)^{2n}e^{-bkx}}{4^n(n!)^2x}~dx$

$=\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{bk}e^{-bkx}}{x}~dx+\int_1^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}a^{2n}b^{2n}e^{bk}C_m^{2n}x^{m-1}e^{-bkx}}{4^n(n!)^2}~dx$

$=e^{bk}E_1(bk)+\int_1^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^na^{2n}b^{2n}e^{bk}(2n)!x^{2m-1}e^{-bkx}}{4^n(2m)!(2n-2m)!(n!)^2}~dx-\int_1^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^na^{2n}b^{2n}e^{bk}(2n)!x^{2m-2}e^{-bkx}}{4^n(2m-1)!(2n-2m+1)!(n!)^2}~dx$

$=e^{bk}E_1(bk)+\int_1^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=m}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^{2n}b^{2n}e^{bk}(2n)!x^{2m-1}e^{-bkx}}{4^n(2m)!(2n-2m)!(n!)^2}~dx-\int_1^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=m}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^{2n}b^{2n}e^{bk}(2n)!x^{2m-2}e^{-bkx}}{4^n(2m-1)!(2n-2m+1)!(n!)^2}~dx$

$=e^{bk}E_1(bk)-\int_1^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}a^{2m+2n+2}b^{2m+2n+2}e^{bk}(2m+2n+2)!x^{2m+1}e^{-bkx}}{4^{m+n+1}(2m+2)!(2n)!((m+n+1)!)^2}~dx+\int_1^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}a^{2m+2n+2}b^{2m+2n+2}e^{bk}(2m+2n+2)!x^{2m}e^{-bkx}}{4^{m+n+1}(2m+1)!(2n+1)!((m+n+1)!)^2}~dx$

$=e^{bk}E_1(bk)+\left[\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^{2m+1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}a^{2m+2n+2}b^{2m+2n+2}e^{bk}(2m+2n+2)!x^pe^{-bkx}}{4^{m+n+1}(2m+2)(2n)!((m+n+1)!)^2p!b^{2m-p+2}k^{2m-p+2}}\right]_1^\infty-\left[\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^{2m}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}a^{2m+2n+2}b^{2m+2n+2}e^{bk}(2m+2n+2)!x^pe^{-bkx}}{4^{m+n+1}(2m+1)(2n+1)!((m+n+1)!)^2p!b^{2m-p+1}k^{2m-p+1}}\right]_1^\infty$

(according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_of_polynomials)

$=e^{bk}E_1(bk)-\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^{2m+1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}a^{2m+2n+2}b^{2n+p}(2m+2n+2)!}{4^{m+n+1}k^{2m-p+2}(2m+2)(2n)!((m+n+1)!)^2p!}+\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^{2m}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}a^{2m+2n+2}b^{2n+p+1}(2m+2n+2)!}{4^{m+n+1}k^{2m-p+1}(2m+1)(2n+1)!((m+n+1)!)^2p!}$

Comment: I think this solution has the same problems as my solution in Approach 1. Mainly that it's difficult to get convergence whenever $a$ is large or when $k$ is small.